# How to create a file locally with ansible templates on the development machine

Tags: ansible

I'm starting out with ansible and I'm looking for a way to create a boilerplate project on the server and on the local environment with ansible playbooks.

I want to use ansible templates locally to create some generic files.
But how would i take ansible to execute something locally?

I read something with local_action but i guess i did not get this right.

This is for the webbserver...but how do i take this and create some files locally?

---

```
- hosts: webservers
      remote_user: someuser
- name: create some file
    template: src=~/workspace/ansible_templates/somefile_template.j2 dest=/etc/somefile/apps-available/someproject.ini
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can delegate tasks with the param `delegate_to` to any host you like, for example:

```
- name: create some file
  template: src=~/workspace/ansible_templates/somefile_template.j2 dest=/etc/somefile/apps-available/someproject.ini
  delegate_to: localhost
```

See [Playbook Delegation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html) in the docs.

If your playbook should in general run locally and no external hosts are involved though, you can simply create a group which contains `localhost` and then run the playbook against this group. In your inventory:

```
[local]
localhost   ansible_connection=local
```

and then in your playbook:

```
hosts: local
```

Comment: Thaanks a lot...but does ansible try to ssh into my localhost? got  SSH Error: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused is this necessary?

Comment: Seems like. I thought they changed that and you don't have to force the local connection. Maybe you have an older Ansible? Anyway, you can add this to your inventory: `localhost              ansible_connection=local` - or if the whole playbook should run locally you can to it like described here: https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_delegation.html#local-playbooks

Answer (score 25):

Ansible has a `local_action` directive to support these scenarios which avoids the `localhost` and/or `ansible_connection` workarounds and is covered in the [Delegation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) docs.

To modify your original example to use `local_action`:

```
- name: create some file
    local_action: template src=~/workspace/ansible_templates/somefile_template.j2 dest=/etc/somefile/apps-available/someproject.ini
```

which looks cleaner.

Comment: fwiw, `local_action:` is just shorter syntax for `delegate_to: localhost`

Answer (score 8):

If you cannot do/allow localhost SSH, you can split the playbook on local actions and remote actions.

The `connection: local` says to not use SSH for a playbook, as shown here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#local-playbooks

Example:

```
# myplaybook.yml

- hosts: remote_machines
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="do stuff in the remote machines"

- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="ran in local ansible machine"

- hosts: remote_machines
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="do more stuff in remote machines"
```

Comment: This solution should be accepted as a correct one. The other two proposals work locally but still require ssh. It makes no sense.